# How to pass longitude and latitude from Android to PHP file using query string

Tags: php, android, mysql, google-maps, gps

I am working on making Android app which using GPS system and fetch current location as longitude and latitude. It had done perfectly but now I want to pass that value to PHP file which contain query and in which these values will used. I try a lot but I can't pass data from Android to PHP file.

This is my GPSTracker.java file. Using this file I get current location:

```
package com.example.mysqltest;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 0; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 0; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                                 .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }       
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    getLocation();
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

}
```

Detail.java file contain my data which are bind from database using current longitude and latitude. In this file on on Create method I called that GPSTracker.java file and also get current Longitude and Latitude on this file successfully.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.shopdetail);

    // create class object
                GPSTracker  gps = new GPSTracker(Shopdetail.this);

                    // check if GPS enabled     
                    if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                        String link = "http://192.168.0.105/PHP/webservice/comments.php?latitude="+latitude+"&longitude="+longitude;    
                        // \n is for new line
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                    }else{
                        // can't get location
                        // GPS or Network is not enabled
                        // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                        gps.showSettingsAlert();


                    }

}
```

and my php code is,

```
   `@$ori_lat = $_REQUEST  ['latitude'];
    @$ori_log  = $_REQUEST  ['longitude'];

if (isset ( $ori_lat ) && isset($ori_log))
{
            $query= " My Query";


  try {
@$stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
@$result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
 catch (PDOException $ex) {
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Database Error!";
die(json_encode($response));
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this snippet!

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
     double ori_lat=location.getLatitude();
     double ori_lon=location.getLongitude(); 
     String link = "http://192.168.2.3/PHP/webservice/comments.php?latitude="+ori_lat+"&longitude="+ori_lon;

      try{
        URL url = new URL(link);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();

        urlConnection.connect();
        switch(urlConnection.getResponseCode()){
                case 200:{
                    Log.i(TAG, "HTTP_OK: You got your response");
                    String response = streamToString(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                    //Now hadle your response
                }
                default:{
                    //Handle
                }
            }

      }catch(IOException e){
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        //Handle exception
      }
}

private String streamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append('\n');
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
}
```

And have a look at **[URLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html)** doc!

You also need INTERNET permission in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: URL url = new URL(link);
  URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection(); this lines give error to me.

Comment: its show red line below this code and suggested to add try catch block. i had also put it but i didnt found actual result what i want

Comment: @user4417231 Just updated the code, it should be cause by IOException that openConnection might throw. Give it a try now and let me know

Comment: tell me exactly  where u got problem.

Comment: @balub he is not handling thrown excpetion

Comment: @Assa   i didnt get error now but i didnt also get data from database. Actually through these latitude and longitude i fetch data from db. They are used in where clause of select query.

Comment: @user4417231 I updated my answer, pleaase mark as answer or +1 if it is helping you, it would be really appreciated:)!

Comment: sorry its not work for me. its show unfortunately my app is stopped. what about php code?

Comment: @user4417231 Post your logcat so we can trace down the problem

Answer (score 0):

first need to get the current location and the requesting to the sever.

code to get current location:

```
public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                // First get location from Network Provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }
```

in manifest we need to set below permssions:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

http GET request:

```
   public void requestServer(double latitude, double longitude) {
        final String link = "http://192.168.0.105/PHP/webservice/comments.php?latitude=" + latitude + "&longitude=" + longitude;

        AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> async = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            public HttpResponse response;

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(link);

                try {
                    response = client.execute(request);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return response.toString();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
        async.execute();
    }
```

in php to get the url data:

```
 script.php

    <?php

    $lat = $_REQUEST ['latitude'];
    $lang = $_REQUEST ['langitude'];

    if (isset ( $lat ) && isset($lang)) {
        // do your stuff    
    } else {
        echo "parameters error.";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79117/discussion-on-answer-by-balu-b-how-to-pass-longitude-and-latitude-from-android-t).

Answer (score 0):

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, link,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
    // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
    mTextView.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
}
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
}
});
// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(stringRequest);
```

take a look at https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html